# How can I get all text node in document fragment?

Tags: javascript, textnode, documentfragment

I get the user selected text:

```
var selection = window.getSelection();
var selectRange = selection.getRangeAt(0);

var content = selectRange.cloneContents(); // DocumentFragment
```

How can I get the `textNode` in the `DocumentFragment` content?

Answer (score 3):

use `textContent`

```
var selection = window.getSelection();
var selectRange = selection.getRangeAt(0);
var content = selectRange.cloneContents(); // DocumentFragment
var text = content.textContent;
```

Comment: Old news but `textContent` gives you a string, not an array of Node.

Answer (score 1):

Filter `fragment.childNodes` to get the text nodes:

```js
const selection = window.getSelection();
const selectRange = selection.getRangeAt(0);
const fragment = selectRange.cloneContents(); // DocumentFragment
// Get the child nodes and filter them to only include text nodes
const textNodes = Array.from(fragment.childNodes).filter(child => child.nodeName === "#text");
```

Answer (score 0):

Combining some tricks it is easy to extract the *text nodes* out of any container node (in this case a *fragment*). The *fragment* part of the question is irrelevant to the extraction part.

Getting all the children of the container, converting them to a "real" Array using the spread operator `...` so `filter` could be used to. Can also skip this part because HTMLCollection does support `forEach` so it's possible to fill an empty Array within that.

Note that `Node.TEXT_NODE` is a DOM *constant* for `3`

```js
// create a demo fragment with some HTML mix of text nodes & elements
var frag = document.createRange().createContextualFragment("<a>1</a> 2 <b>3</b> 4.");

// now the work begins: get only the text nodes from the fragment
var textNodes = [...frag.childNodes].filter(node => node.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE)

// print the text nodes as an array
console.log( textNodes.map(node => node.textContent) )
```